# Which .Net collection interface to use when in a domain model?

Tags: .net, collections, domain-driven-design

Using the Northwind schema as an example which collection interface would you use in the following circumstances.

[image: Northwind Schema]
<sub>(source: [techmatica.com](http://northwind.techmatica.com/images/NorthwindLayout.JPG))</sub>
.

**Customer**

Customer has a collection of Orders. For the purpose of this example the Orders collection is readonly.

**Order**

An Order has collection of OrderDetails. An OrderDetail can be added to the collection.

**Employee**

An Employee has collection of Territories. An Employee can belong to 0 or more Territories but TerritoryId must be unique.

Comment: not clear on the question.  why is the Orders collection readonly?

Comment: @AlexLo. Edited question to stipulate Orders collection is readonly for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) <strike>in all three cases</strike> for Orders and OrderDetails. There is no specific interface for readonly collections, this is handled by the implementation (you could use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as the concrete type in that case). You could also use `IList<T>`, but it only adds support for access by index, which usually doesn't really make sense in a relational model.

For Territories, you could use [`ISet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) (assuming you're using .NET 4.0). Classes that implement this interface don't allow duplicate items.

Comment: The safest read only collection is IEnumerable<T>, as ICollection supports Add()

Comment: Yes, I guess IEnumerable<T> would be OK too. But it doesn't really prevent modification of the collection: if the actual collection is an ICollection<T>, you can still cast to ICollection<T> and then call Add...

Comment: ICollection<T> interface does not stipulate that items must be unique. Therefore does it not break the requirements for Customer.Territories?

Comment: I missed that requirement when reading your question, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Needs a bit more info.  For example, why is Orders collection read-only?  How are these collections to be used? There are many variables here.

The key is, expose them as the most simple interface that meets your needs.  Don't use an `ICollection<T>` if you always simply iterate over the list as a whole and never add to it.  On the other hand, don't use an `IEnumerable<T>` if you find yourself wanting to cast to an `IList<T>` to add or get items by index.

For example, if you are created a model for presentation via MVVM, I may suggest that you use a `BindingList`.   If you only do summing operations on orders, I may suggest a simple `IEnumerable<T>`.  Etc